# How to display a list of objects which contains a list of objects as a table?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have 2 classes in java like this:

```
public class Class1{

private String a;
private String b;
private List<Class2> list;
// Assume constructor, getter & setters
}

public class Class2{

private String c;
private String b;
// Assume constructor, getter & setters
}
```

And in my .jsp, I'm trying something like this:

```
**<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th> col1 </th>
        <th> col2 </th>
        <th> col3 </th>
        <th> col4 </th>
       </tr>
      <%
       **List<Class1> list1 = // assume populated;**
       for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++){
            Class1 obj = list1.get(i);
       %>
    <tr>
           <td><%=obj.getA()%></td>
           <td><%=obj.getB()%></td>
           <td>
             <table>
                 <tbody>
         <%
          List<Class2> list2 = obj.getList();
          for(int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++){
              Class2 obj2 = list2.get(j);
         %>
                  <tr>
                     <td><%=obj2.getC()%></td>
                     <td><%=obj2.getD()%></td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
       </td>
          <%
           }
           %>
      </tr>
       <%
        }
        %>
    </tbody>
 </table>**
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to obtain a table that looks this one in the image:
[image]

But what I obtain is something like this:

[image]

The problem is I can't place the table data under the right table head.

If I missed some info, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is `javascript` being used here?

Comment: A program, even if you call it a 'script,' written in Java does not make that program JavaScript; the languages [tag:java] and [tag:javascript] are different languages entirely.

Comment: It was a mistake. I know there is a difference between javascript and java, thanks lads.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop seems to be broken. You should go with a loop considering following structure:

```
<td>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      
        <tr><td>c1(obj1)</td></tr>
         <tr><td>c1(obj2)</td></tr>
      
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </td>
  
  <td>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      
        <tr><td>d1(obj1)</td></tr>
         <tr><td>d1(obj2)</td></tr>
      
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </td>
```